# Avoid duplicate records from a particular column of a table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table as shown in the image.In Number column, the values are appeared more than once (for example 63 appeared twice). I would like to keep only one value. Please see my code:
delete from t1 where

```
  (SELECT *,row_number() OVER (          
          PARTITION BY 
            Number
          ORDER BY 
            Date) as rn from t1  where   rn > 1)
```

It shows error. Can anyone please assist.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSILM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column created by row_number() was not accessed by your main query, in order to enable that, you can create a quick sub query and use the desired filter

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT *,
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Number ORDER BY Date) as rn 
FROM t1 ) T
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks dsk. It is fine now. Just want to know what is T here.

Comment: That is the reference of the Table , instead of full table name , you cn use T.column_name likewise

Answer (score 0):

The `partition by` determines how row numbers repeat.  The row numbers are assigned per group of `partition by` keys.  So, you can get duplicates.

If you want a unique row number over all rows, just leave out the `partition by`:

```
select t1.*
from (select t1.*,
            row_number() over (order by date) as rn        
      from t1 
     ) t1
where rn > 1
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, it says : Unrecognized name: rn at [5:7]. Can you pls assist.

Comment: @nrad . . . `rn` is defined in the subquery.  It is defined.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep only one value, rn = 1 instead of "> 1"